# How to align block of PHP/JavaScript code?

Tags: phpstorm

In My PhpStorm 2019.2.5 is it possible to align some PHP code from

```
$show_only_top_currencies   = $this->requestData['show_only_top_currencies'] ?? false;
$retArray                 = ['message' => ''];
$currenciesCount          = Currency::getByActive(true)->count();
$base_currency        = Settings::getValue('base_currency', CheckValueType::cvtString, '');
```

into :

```
$show_only_top_currencies = $this->requestData['show_only_top_currencies'] ?? false;
$retArray                 = ['message' => ''];
$currenciesCount          = Currency::getByActive(true)->count();
$base_currency            = Settings::getValue('base_currency', CheckValueType::cvtString, '');
```

?

and same for JavaScript code?

Comment: Did you try switching "Variable declarations" to "Align: When grouped" in "Editor | Code Style | JavaScript"  already?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible for PHP code: the setting is called "Align consecutive assignments". This is where you can find it in PhpStorm 2020.3.2:

[image]

A similiar setting can be found for JS code, "Variable declarations: Align when grouped".

You can fiddle around with both settings and see the effect in the code snippets - this might help to find other helpful options

Comment: I tried to find this option under Setting and failed.
Next was opened : https://prnt.sc/yeb67r
Could you please to check if this option is in my PhpStorm 2019.2.5  ?
Actually, I expected something like : I select rows of text and by some menu action(hot key)
aligmnent is applied. Are there something like that ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using 2020.3 - I've attached a screenshot

Comment: Looks like my  PhpStorm 2019.2.5 has no this functionality ?

Comment: @mstdmstd Of course it's there. Here is an answer from 2016 for PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39287563/783119 For JavaScript (from 2014): https://stackoverflow.com/a/22360509/783119 .

Comment: @mstdmstd *"I expected something like : I select rows of text and by some menu action(hot key) aligmnent is applied."* If you need that then try string related plugins, I remember seeing a few where description says that they can format tabular data (which is what an alignment is in an essence). Start with String Manipulation plugin (Sort Tokens action I believe).